# Is it possible to control android TV with Raspberry pi over wi-fi?

Tags: remote

I am unable to find any API references for building remote apps for Android TV. However, considering there are multiple third party apps on the Play store which can control Android TVs, I was wondering if it is possible to do the same from Linux on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Something like [this](https://renative.org/docs/androidtv) ? [github project](https://github.com/pavjacko/renative)

Comment: Not Pi specific.  If Linux can do it then the Pi can do it.

Comment: If the android tv has a webinterface you can probably use it via http requests

Answer (score 2):

Of course yes. You can connect to Android TV via ADB. Next, send the commands to the ADB mode of the TV.

---

### Connect to the TV:

**-** Install ADB package on the Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install adb
```

**-** Turn on ADB on the TV and find the TV's IP address then try to connect as port `5555`. Assume that the IP address of the TV is `192.168.1.100`:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.100:5555
```

**-** Accept on the TV, a dialog like picture below:

[image]

Now, you've connected to the TV and also can run any ADB commands according to your TV brand.

You need to just find ADB commands for changing the channel, input, brightness level, etc as reported by your TV brand's RCKey.

---

### ADB Commands:

With the help of [this link - *Darren's AndroidTV Automation Framework*](https://github.com/DarrenVictoriano/daaf), you would be able to change states of the TV as I said above. It will help you enough and you might not need more information.

To find your TV's RCKey, check [this link - *Hacking an Android TV*](https://medium.com/@drakkars/hacking-an-android-tv-in-2-minutes-7b6f29518ff3) out.

If you are familiar with java, read [this link - *Android TV KeyEvent*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) to create your own framework!

---

Overall, with the help of the ADB connection, you can achieve the goal that you said.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look this up. One question though, does this ADB connection work over wi-fi? Or I'll have to first connect using USB?

Comment: @gouravkr If you are asking in general, Android OS on smartphones, you must connect it by USB cable but Android TV is different. You are able to connect it without any USB connection. Just enable ADB on the TV.